# Can I convert my Xoom 3G firmware to Xoom WiFi or otherwise use the WiFi version of Jelly Bean?

Tags: motorola-xoom, 4.1-jelly-bean

So I have a Xoom 3G and I only use Wi-Fi. Jelly Bean is coming out for the WiFi-only version and of course Verizon is going to make sure that the 3G/4G version doesn't get Jelly Bean till Key Lime Pie is out. So my questions are: Would the WiFi version work on my Xoom? If so, can I somehow spoof it to think it's a WiFi version to get the update and/or can I manually update to the WiFi Jelly Bean?

Comment: I have an answer in my inbox but I don't see it here? The response shows as "Well you can install it manually, but you won't have 3G/4G data."  Does that sound legit?  If so, where do I learn how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to install a wifi only rom manually, I`ve just gone to ICS with 3g and its great.

found these links useful:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfHwd2Nxw1U

http://www.icsforums.com/forum/showthread/6398

http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/Motorola_Xoom

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks...now the 3g should have already had the OTA ICS, right?  (BTW, wow, you JUST posted this and I just checked for the first time this morning.)

Comment: One last question...if I install my own ROM am I forever off the automated OTA upgrades?  I'd like when the official Xoom 3g Jelly Bean comes out to be on it.

Comment: @GeeksOnHugs: generally yes, you will no longer be able to OTA unless you reflash back to stock version.

Comment: @LieRyan thanks :-)  The wifi version is soak testing now :-)